# Проблема с чтением STDIN из консольной команды в Laravel 5.8 под Windows

Tags: php, laravel, stdin

Что-то очень странное происходит со стандартным потоком при попытке прочитать его из консольной команды в проекте на Laravel. Если запустить команду, например, `php artisan test-command < file.txt` с кодом типа:

```
    public function handle()
    {
        while (($s = fgets(STDIN)) !== false) {
            var_dump($s);
        }
    }
```

или

```
    public function handle()
    {
        var_dump(file_get_contents('php://stdin'));
    }
```

то скрипт не выводит ничего. Скрипт ведёт себя так, как будто в него передали пустой файл. При этом в самом начале `feof(STDIN)` возвращает `false`. Но первое же чтение через `fgets(STDIN)` возвращает `false`. И уже после этого `feof(STDIN)` возвращает `true`.

Этот же код, размещённый не в команде Laravel, а в голом PHP-скрипте, естественно работает как надо без каких-либо сюрпризов.

Если запустить скрипт без передачи в него файла (`php artisan test-command`), то скрипт будет читать ввод с клавиатуры и тут всё хорошо. Скрипт будет получать ввод вплоть до строки `Ctrl+Z` и `Enter`. То есть проблема проявляется только при передаче потока из файла или другой программы (`cat file.txt | php artisan test-command` имеет тот же результат).

Проявляется данная проблема под Windows (в моём случае 10). Под Linux проблема не замечена. Версия Laravel 5.8.38 Хочется понять откуда растут ноги у этой проблемы. Кто-нибудь с таким сталкивался?

Comment: А почему не использовать стандартный механизм [Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/artisan#prompting-for-input) для этого?

Comment: @DanielProtopopov Это не совсем то, что мне нужно. Мне не нужна интерактивность, не надо задавать пользователю вопросы. Мне нужно просто прочитать STDIN. Туда мне должен передаваться список номеров заказов.